# SocketIO: Node.js and Browser Client js communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, server, socket.io

I am trying to send data bidirectionally between a node server and browser client.

I can get information from the Node server to the browser client but not vice versa. I dont understand what I am doing wrong, please help.

### Node `server.js`

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var socketTx = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'))

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000');
});

// 1) Send initial data from node to browser
setInterval( function() {
  var msg = Math.random();
  socketTx.emit('Node', msg);
}, 1000);

var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socketRx = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {reconnect: true});

// 4) Receive data from browser and log in node console
socketRx.on('Browser', function(msg){
  console.log(msg);
});
```

### Browser `index.html`

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="message"></div>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="socket.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Browser `socket.js`

```
var socketRx = io();
var socketTx = io();

// 2) Receive initial data from node and display in browser
socketRx.on('Node', function(msg){
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg;

  // 3) Send data from browser back to node
  socketTx.emit('Browser', msg);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with socket.io, sorry if there are mistakes.
By refering to [this official document](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/), I fixed `server.js` as below.
It has been working fine in my environment. Please try this code.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var socketTx = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'))

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000');
});

// 1) Send initial data from node to browser
setInterval( function() {
  var msg = Math.random();
  socketTx.emit('Node', msg);
}, 1000);

var io = require('socket.io-client');
io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {reconnect: true});

// 4) Receive data from browser and log in node console
socketTx.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('Browser', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!